# Inserting multiple elements into a 2D block

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I am attempting to calculate the energy of a series of elements inside a vector of vectors. As soon as the particular element has the right energy, it is then pushed into another vector of vectors. Here is an example because it is hard to explain:

```
bool energy(const std::vector<double> &vals)
{
  float sum = 0.0;
  for(unsigned i=0; (i < vals.size()); i++)
  {
     sum += (vals[i]*vals[i]);
  }
  //cout << sum << endl;
  return (sum >= 5);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

 std::vector<vector<double> > vals {

    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, // This has an energy of "0" -> does not count
    {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, // This has an energy of "5" -> push_back to vector[0]
    {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, // This has an energy of "5" -> push_back to vector[0]
    {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, // This has an energy of "5" -> push_back to vector[0]
    {1, 2, 1, 1, 1}, //This has an energy of "5" -> push_back to vector[0]
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, // This has an energy of "0" -> does not count && start a new 
                                // vector
    {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, // This has an energy of "55" -> push_back to vector[1]
    {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, // This has an energy of "55" -> push_back to vector[1]
    {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, // This has an energy of "55" -> push_back to vector[1]
    {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} // This has an energy of "55" -> push_back to vector[1]
};
std::vector<vector<double> > clusters; 
std::vector<vector<double> > tmp;

//std::for_each(vals.begin(), vals.end(), energy);

int j = 0;

for(unsigned i=0; (i < vals.size()); i++)
{
    if(energy(vals[i]))
    {
        clusters.resize(j + 1);
        clusters[j] = vals[i];
    }else if(!energy(vals[i]) && energy(vals[i+1]))
    {
        j++;
    }
}

for(unsigned i=0; (i < clusters.size()); i++)
{
    for(unsigned j=0; (j < clusters[i].size()); j++)
    {
        cout << clusters[i][j] << ' ';
    }
    cout << endl;
}
 }
```

**What should happen**

There should be `2` elements of the vector of vectors named `clusters` each containing the values of:

`clusters[0] = {
                    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
            1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
            1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
            1, 2, 1, 1, 1
                  };`

```
`clusters[1] = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 
      1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
      1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 
      1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`
```

**What is happening?**

The vector of vectors seem to be over-riding the blocks that get inserted into them. So instead of the above, I just get the last element that it found so:

```
`cluster[0] = {1 2 1 1 1}
cluster[1] = {1 2 3 4 5}`
```

What I was thinking and attempting was to store each of the "blocks" inside a vector of vectors that contain the sufficient energy and then push all these values inside a `vector<double>` and then insert this vector inside the block of clusters..

Is there an alternative way, a much simpler solution to this problem?

Comment: {1, 2, 1, 1, 1}, //This has an energy of "8"

Comment: @cpp Sorry, I changed the values slightly to make sure I was right and it was just storing the last elements of the blocks. It should still store each element between the {0, 0, .....} and {0, 0, ....} any suggestions?

Comment: Calling `resize` and then setting the new space to the desired vector is unnecessary.  Just call `clusters.push_back(vals[i])`, which is doing the same thing.  Your question seems to imply that you want to merge all of the low energy vectors into a single vector (same for high energy vectors).  Is that correct?

Comment: @ZacHowland Yes, merge all of the high energy vectors into one.. Then push these into the `clusters` vector at the current position.. Does this make sense? I'm at a loss about what approach to take

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Corrected code:

```
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

bool energy(const std::vector<double> &vals)
{
  float sum = 0.0;
  for(unsigned i=0; (i < vals.size()); i++)
  {
     sum += (vals[i]*vals[i]);
  }
  //cout << sum << endl;
  return (sum >= 5);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

 std::vector<vector<double> > vals {

    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, // This has an energy of "0" -> does not count
    {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, // This has an energy of "5" -> push_back to vector[0]
    {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, // This has an energy of "5" -> push_back to vector[0]
    {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, // This has an energy of "5" -> push_back to vector[0]
    {1, 2, 1, 1, 1}, //This has an energy of "5" -> push_back to vector[0]
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, // This has an energy of "0" -> does not count && start a new
                                // vector
    {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, // This has an energy of "55" -> push_back to vector[1]
    {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, // This has an energy of "55" -> push_back to vector[1]
    {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, // This has an energy of "55" -> push_back to vector[1]
    {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} // This has an energy of "55" -> push_back to vector[1]
};
std::vector<vector<double> > tmp(vals.size());
std::vector<vector<double> > clusters(vals.size());

int j = 0;

for(unsigned i=0; (i < vals.size()); i++)
{
    if(energy(vals[i]))
    {
        clusters[j].insert(clusters[j].end(), vals[i].begin(), vals[i].end());
    }else if(!energy(vals[i]) && energy(vals[i+1]))
    {
        j++;
    }
}

for(unsigned i=0; (i < clusters.size()); i++)
{
    for(unsigned j=0; (j < clusters[i].size()); j++)
    {
        cout << clusters[i][j] << ' ';
    }
    cout << endl;
}
 }
```

The output is:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 
1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: Thank you for this. But, this does not merge all of the high frequency values.. For example: `for(unsigned i=0; (i < clusters[1].size()); i++)
 {
  cout << clusters[1][i];
 }` has to display the entire vector, not just one line.. If this makes sense? I.e. `clusters.size();` should only be 2 since there are only 2 pairs of high frequency values..

Comment: dude, you are a legend :) Thank you so much! I didn't think it would be this simple so thanks! I've just got to sort the size issue out and then I'm all done! TY

Answer (score 0):

I changed a piece of code make it works

```
  int j = 0;

  for(unsigned i=0; (i < vals.size()); i++)
  {
      if(energy(vals[i])) {
          clusters[j].insert(clusters[j].end, vals[i].begin(), vals[i].end());
      }
      if(!energy(vals[i]) && energy(vals[i+1])) {
        clusters.push_back( tmp );
        ++j;
      }

  }
```

Don't use resize. You can just push_back an empty vector into your clusters.

And for each operation to append a vector, just using insert by range

```
void insert (iterator position, InputIterator first, InputIterator last);
```

Ref: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
for(unsigned i=0; (i < vals.size()); i++)
{
    if(energy(vals[i]))
    {
        clusters.resize(j + 1);
        clusters[j] = vals[i];
    }
    else if(!energy(vals[i]) && energy(vals[i+1]))
    {
        j++;
    }
}
```

First of all, your `energy` function returns an `int`, so when the return value is non-zero, it will evaluate the condition to `true`, and when it is 0, it will be `false`.

Second, you are effectively doing a `push_back` in the `if` branch, but you are only pushing the current vector (you aren't appending it to an existing vector).

To fix this, I would recommend using a `map<int, vector<int>>` so you can quickly reference each cluster (e.g. the ones with energy of 5 would have a key of 5, so you would either create a new vector and insert those values, or append to the one that already exists there).  If you need it in a vector of vectors, you can always iterate through the map after you have them sorted and swap them into the vector of vectors.

Comment: Thanks Zac!! Will using a `std::map<int, vector<int>>` allow me to merge all of the clusters together? Since, that is my overall outcome of this problem.

Comment: Not directly, but yes.  It will allow you to access the vectors of the same energy level quickly.  The merging is done through the use of the `insert` function or using `std::copy(vals[i].begin(), vals[i].end(), std::back_inserter(myMap[myEnergy]));`

Answer (score 0):

you could simplify a lot your code, so it would be much more easy to read and understand, for example take you energy function, you could write it in a single line using algorithms:

```
return std::inner_product(vals.begin(), vals.end(), vals.begin(), 0.) >= 5;
```